# Menu "new" edit not possible, click does not lead to any action (type: page library)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitepages, libraries

I have the problem that I cannot edit the "New" menu of my site pages library (type: site pages library) in SharePoint Online. When I click on the drop-down menu "new" and click on the bottom menu item "Edit New" nothing happens.

[image: site pages library menu]

In a document library this ability to "Edit New Menu" works correctly. I have already created new SharePoint sites (team sites) and tried it there, unfortunately, also without success.

Comment: I can confirm this in two different tenants that I have access to, that I can successfully Edit the "New" menu in all Libraries except for the default "Site Pages" library.  I would say that this unfortunately appears to be a bug in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2):

@willman & @sharepointnewbie:

The Site pages library in modern (and classic) sites is a special library in SharePoint.  It is not meant to be treated like other document libraries. As such, you need to manage the +New menu differently. 
Add additional content types to the library itself and ensure that the option to make the content type visible on the New Button is set to yes.

See attached images

[image: new button for the site pages library]

[image: site pages library settings page]